# Spring Boot won't serve updated external static content

Tags: spring, spring-boot, static-content

Here is the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
  }
}

@Configuration
class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/api/**")
            .setCachePeriod(0)
            .addResourceLocations("file:public/");
  }
}
```

I am using maven.  When I package the code into a jar, I place the jar in the same directory as a 'public' folder.  Note that this public folder is external to the jar.  The public folder contains static content.  I am able to access that static content by hitting `http://localhost:8080/api/static-content.html`.  However, when I manually update the static content I don't see the changes, and when I add a new file to that folder, I get back a 404.

How do get a spring boot web app to serve the updated static content?

Comment: You could try to add *spring-boot-devtools* to your project as it enables hotswapping.